# PHP syntax ?> <?

Tags: php, syntax

I cannot figure out what the ?> <? syntax is doing in this code. I have searched the php syntax page    and this is not an opening or closing tag nor a short open tag. The code will not compile without it and I am getting a strange coloring in the curly brackets that follow.

```
if(isset($_POST)){?>
            <form method="POST" action="Form_Index.php">
            User <input type="text" name="userTwo"></input><br/>
            Pass <input type="password" name="passTwo"></input><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go"></input>
            </form>
    <?}
```

Comment: `?>` is **always** the closing tag for the PHP context. `<?` is a short-open-tag and should be avoided for portability in favour of `<?php`. The code between `?>` and `<?` is just static HTML that will be added directly to the output buffer

Comment: The manual page you're looking for is here ~ https://www.php.net/manual/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: This is not correct. If you look closely you will see the code has ?> not <?. If I switch the ? and the > around the code does not work. Also, I I use <?php it does not work.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following. Your code has some PHP, an opening brace `{`, then the closing `?>`, then some static HTML, then the open-short-tag `<?` and then finally `}`. If it helps you understand it better, think of it like `if (isset($_POST)) { echo '<form>...</form>'; }` where the content between `?>` and `<?` replaces the `echo`

Comment: No worries, so here is the deal, the code works... however if I use "<?php" following the </form> tag the code does not work. It is super basic and I get it, an undergrad can probably answer the question.  I've been a professional programer for over 10 years, php is a newish syntax to me. I just want to understand what is happening here. Why is my server throwing a fit?  <? works... <?php does not.

Comment: What's the error? If you replace `<? }` with `<?php }`, it should be exactly the same. Just don't forget that closing`}`

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'  I've played around with adding and deleting closing braces, adding and deleting short-open-tags. The code wants to work one way, it's just that way is not in keeping with what I'm used to seeing. It's not a big deal, I just saw this as an opportunity to learn some fundamentals. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah, I think I see. When you use `<?php`, there must be at least one whitespace character following it. So this is bad - `<?php}`, this is good - `<?php }` ~ https://3v4l.org/Pc7dQ. Personally, I always preferred the alt syntax ~ https://3v4l.org/Nm9H0

Comment: You sir, are a hero; the whitespace did it. Thank you for solving this question.

Answer (score -1):

Your PHP code lives between `<?php` and `?>`

So the `?>` means that PHP stops there, and HTML starts.

`<?` Is just a short notation for `<?php`.

To add to the confusion, the `?>` close tag is optional at the end of a file.